# Vue (with Vite) page not loading with Flask: MIME type of "text/html" instead of JavaScript

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/full-stack-single-page-application-with-vue-js-and-flask-b1e036315532) to build a full stack app with Vue and Flask. I am using the [latest method](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application) to use Vue instead of the webpack instructions in the tutorial.

I am able to get the frontend loading on port 5173 and the flask backend to run on port 5000, but the frontend experience is not showing up on the tab that is running port 5000 (I would expect it to load the same page as is on port 5173). In the console is gives me an error `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

The error comes up twice and looks like its coming from two files (client(?) and main.ts). I'm not sure what client is but here is my main.ts (it's just using the base template that is automatically set up):

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import './assets/main.css'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks!